# Custom Page Template

Tags: template

I'd like to create a page template in a team site that has a few elements each time I create the page. These elements would include..

- Predefined headings and text areas
- An embedded issues app part pre-filtered by some meta data
- An embedded document app part linked to a document library based on meta data

In a normal ASP.NET site I can see how to accomplish this but, with SharePoint, I'm not so clear and am ending up with a lot of repetitive tasks each time I create a page.

I'm assuming that there is must be a way of doing this relatively easily? Any thoughts or links to help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom **publishing page layout** with Design Manager and SharePoint Designer. Here's [one of the many articles](http://sharepointcommunity.de/blogs/owirkus/archive/2013/07/15/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-custom-page-layout.aspx) about how to do it. There is also an [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822368.aspx).

You need the **publishing features** to be activated. They are disabled on a team site by default.